# How to declare functional parameters in OCaml/ReasonML?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

There are two functions; **funA** and **funB**, respectively. `a.i, a.o, ah, w, c` are arrays in the function **funA**. The function **funA** shall be passed as a functional parameter to the function **funB** and the arrays should be able to be accessed by the function **funB**. Unfortunately, the syntax checker encountered an error "Error: Unbound record field a". Please comment, how to declare functional parameters in OCaml/ReasonML?

**Full list**

```
module Test = {
    let vector = Array.init;
    let matrix = (m, n, f) => vector(m, i => vector(n, f(i)));
    let length = Array.length;
    let rand = (x0, x1) => x0 +. Random.float(x1 -. x0);
    let funA = (ni, nh, no) => {
      let init = (fi, fo) => {
        let i = matrix(ni + 1, nh, fi);
        let o = matrix(nh, no, fo);
        ();
      };

      let a = {
        let i = vector(ni + 1, _ => 1.0);
        let o = vector(no, _ => 1.0);
        ();
      };

      let ah = vector(nh, _ => 1.0);
      let w = init((_, _) => rand(-0.2, 0.4), (_, _) => rand(-2.0, 4.0));
      let c = init((_, _) => 0.0, (_, _) => 0.0);
      ();
    };

    let funB = (net, inputs) => {
      let (ni, nh, no) = (
        length(net.a.i),
        length(net.ah),
        length(net.a.o),
      );
      ();
    };
  };
```

Comment: Where are the records defined? A record needs to be in scope in order to be used, which you can do either by annotating the type or by opening the containing module where it's used, so that the type can be inferred from the fields used.

Comment: @glennsl , I have no idea how to define records which to be used in this case. Is it same as struct in C programming? Would you suggest a link to me for reference.

Comment: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#s:tut-recvariants

Comment: Or in more of a tutorial form: https://dev.realworldocaml.org/records.html

Comment: Or for reason specifically (which I forgot this question was about): https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/record

Comment: All are good resources you should try to refer to before asking questions.

Comment: I have already seen the resources before ask a question. From a coding design point of view, I prefer to pass a function over pass a type/record as a parameter of funB.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the functional parameter **funA** which is inaccessible in the function **funB**, apply the following type at the beginning of the module.

```
module Test = {

    type io('a) = {
      i: 'a,
      o: 'a,
    };

    type vec = array(float);

    type mat = array(vec);

    type funA = {
      a: io(vec),
      ah: vec,
      w: io(mat),
      c: io(mat),
    };

.......
```